# Search function in php using pdo

Tags: php, mysql, search, pdo

I've been tasked with building a pretty simple search function for my groups project and I am currently stuck and can't go no further!

The idea is to search with keywords (gold, watch, leather for example), and when you hit search it's supposed to send a Select Query to the Database.

I exploded the get array and trimmed it from spaces and put % around the words, then I imploded them to one string called `$searchQuery`.

I have a connection to the database and when I search on a single word (just gold or watch for example), it works great and gives me the result I expect, but as soon as there is more than one word, it just says "No products found".

Below, you'll find my code. The first one is the form, the secon one is the search function pretty much. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<form action="index.php?action=search" method="get">

    <input type="text" name="q">
    <button type="submit">Sök</button>

</form>
```

The search function code

```
<?php
 var_dump($_GET['q']);

 $query = explode(",", $_GET['q']);
 var_dump($query);
 $searchQuery = array();

foreach($query as $question) {
  $question = trim($question);
  $question = "%".$question."%";
  $searchQuery[] = $question;
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($searchQuery);
echo "</pre>"; 

$searchQuery = implode(' AND title LIKE ', $searchQuery);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($searchQuery);
echo "</pre>";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE title LIKE :search";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':search', $searchQuery);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($result);
echo "</pre>";

$count = $stmt->rowCount();
?> 

<ul>
<?
 if($count == 0) {
   echo "Inga produkter hittades";
 } else {
 foreach ($result as $product) {
    echo "<li>";
    echo $product['title'].", ".$product['price'].":-";
    echo "</li>";
  }
}

?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Should your AND be an OR?

Comment: I tried replacing the AND with an OR, but it still won't give me anything. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You need to separate out the query from the placeholder as well. As it stands you're passing the `AND title LIKE` parts of the query as the value to filter by. Placeholders are not an alternative concatenation function.

Comment: `?action=search` you're also not using that part which PHP is looking for a `$_GET['action']` array and equaling to "search".

Comment: I think I get what you mean, but could you explain it further? The `AND title LIKE` shouldn't be in the implode function?
Edit: The ?action=search is working as it should, the `$_GET['action']` is "connected" through the index page

Comment: Amazingly it does, I'm a bit baffled myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code full of errors.

First of all `$question = "%".$question."%";` will generate `LIKE %some%` - error in sql. Should be `$searchQuery[] = "'%".trim($question)."%'";`

Second your `WHERE title LIKE :search` put whole `AND LIKE '%asd%' AND LIKE '%sdf%'` into single parameter and will be parsed as string. Even if this part would work, you will bump in query `WHERE title LIKE AND LIKE '%asd%' AND LIKE '%sdf%'` - another sql error.

---

I think your code should be something like

```
$likes = [];

foreach($query as $question) {
    $likes[] = "'%".trim($question)."%'";
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products";

if (!empty($likes)) {
   $sql .= " WHERE title LIKE "
       .array_shift($likes) // remove first element from array
       .implode(" OR title LIKE ", $likes); // implode rests with 'OR'
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Yes! Got it to work now!
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @KarlEdenstål this answer defeats the very purpose of prepared statements and makes your code **vulnerable to SQL injection**

Comment: @Your Common Sense can I read more about prepared statements in your PDO tutorial? I'm just getting started on the search function, I'll definitely work on making it more secure! It's fun being a beginner! Thanks for the heads up!